# How to make Yargs display examples in command specific "help"?

Tags: command-line-interface, yargs

Typing -h prints normal help and I can add examples using the .example() API.

However, this is not printed when displaying help for a command:

```
myApp foobar -h
or
myApp foobar help
```

I would like to print examples for the command "foobar" specifically, and not for the app in general. How can I do that?

Comment: Also asked and answered on the Yarps repo: https://github.com/yargs/yargs/issues/2351